# Converting string to java.util.date

Tags: java, date, date-conversion

I am working with date strings that need to be converted to java.util.date objects.

I'm using the following code to do this:

```
public void setDates(String from, String to) throws ParseException
{
    Date fromDate = new Date();
    Date toDate = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    fromDate = df.parse(from);
    toDate = df.parse(to);

    this.setDepartDate(fromDate);
    this.setReturnDate(toDate);
}
```

The problem is that the string values that I have to convert are always(And I have no control over this) in the following format: "20 September, 2013".

This causes my function to through a ParseException when it reaches `fromDate = df.parse(from);`

Could anyone help me understand why, and perhaps suggest a solution?

Comment: so set to SimpleDateFormat to the format expected

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the [`SimpleDateFormat` JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for the available format options, but basically, you need to change your date format to something more like `dd MMMM, yyyy`

```
try {
    String dateValue = "20 September, 2013";
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy");
    Date date = df.parse(dateValue);
    System.out.println(date);
} catch (ParseException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which outputs...

```
Fri Sep 20 00:00:00 EST 2013
```

Comment: @GyroGearless Yep, caught it to :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks! I was under the impression that the format you gave the SimpleDateFormat object was the format you wanted the date in after parsing it, not the format of the string you were giving it.

Comment: @Skytiger: `parse()` is for parsing (reading), `format()` is for formatting (writing).

Comment: @Skytiger Actually both can be true.  You can use the (Simple)DateFormat to convert from date to string or from string to date.  The format you pass to the constructor then depends on what you would like the instance to do.

Answer (score 6):

As per the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) use following format

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMMM, yyyy");
```

Also decide if this parsing needs to be [Lenient](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) or not and if it needs to be strict use `setLenient(false)`

> By default, parsing is lenient: If the input is not in the form used
>   by this object's format method but can still be parsed as a date, then
>   the parse succeeds. Clients may insist on strict adherence to the
>   format by calling setLenient(false).

Also note that `SimpleDateFormat` is not threadsafe. If there is a choice I recommend using [Joda Time Library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Formatters)  that provide much enhanced functionality.

Answer (score 5):

You wrote

> [...] in the following format: "20 September, 2013".

Then your `SimpleDateFormat` should be

```
"dd MMM, yyyy"
```

You can check out the [`SimpleDateFormat` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 4):

When you parse a date, you need to know some context or use some assumptions.  You can use SimpleDateFormat, but you may need to pre-parse the string to see which format it is before you use it.  You may have to try multiple format to see if one or more way to parse the date.

BTW is 01/02/30 the 1st Feb 1930 or 2nd Jan 2030 or 30th feb 2001, you need to know something about what the date is likely to mean or have some control over the format.

Answer (score 1):

## `LocalDate`

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the troublesome old date-time classes (`Date`, `Calendar`, etc.) years ago.

```
String input = "20 September, 2013" ;
Locale locale = Locale.US ; // Determines the human language and cultural norms used in parsing the input string. 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "d MMMM, uuuu" , locale ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/eFF89J).

> ld.toString(): 2013-09-20

## `ZonedDateTime`

If you want a time-of-day with that date, such as the first moment of the day, you must specify a time zone. A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your [desired/expected time zone][2] explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

Apply that `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Never assume the day starts at 00:00:00. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) mean the day may start at another time such as 01:00:00. Let *java.time* determine the first moment of the day.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

## `Instant`

To adjust into UTC, extract an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use following date **pattern**, `dd MMMM, yyyy`

Try this code,

```
        String dateValue = "20 September, 2013";
        // Type of different Month views        
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy"); //20 September, 2013
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM, yyyy");  //20 09, 2013
        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy"); //20 Sep, 2013 
        Date date = sdf.parse(dateValue); // returns date object
        System.out.println(date); // outputs: Fri Sep 20 00:00:00 IST 2013
```

Comment: (A) Wasn't this covered already in the other Answers posted years ago? (B) `Date` is the wrong type for a date-only value, as that class represents a date with a time-of-day in UTC.